# German RepRap NEO only heats to 130°C

Tags: extruder

I have a new German RepRap NEO 3D printer, and when I try heating the Extruder to 215°C with Repetier-Host Mac 1.0.1, it always stops at 130°C - does anybody have an idea what could be the reason?

Comment: A 24V heater on a 12V system might do this.

Answer (score 1):

A few possiblitites.

You wire is too small. If your wire is HOT that is a fire hazard.

Your thermistor is bad. Check with a high temp heat probe or try replacing thermistor.

Your heating element is bad (rare).

Last it could be a limit in your firmware. But that would surprise me.

Any chance you have the bed and the hotend reversed? If you had the Bed as Hotend, then it would max out around 100. This last one I would say is most likely..

Comment: I think that there is a high chance that the problem lies somewhere connected to the temperature limit of the heated bed. Maybe the hotend is connected as bed. Here we'd need more information from the author.

Comment: The heated bed usually stops at 100ish. Hotend -- could be a bad heater core. There are a lot of cheapo crap ones on ebay.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that your thermistor is either broken or not screwed in correctly. If this is not the case you should either check look through your firmware for issues, or buy a new heater cartridge and thermistor.